# How to change colors, so that the bars become visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

[image]  How can I change make the bar chart visible? i tried to change colors, however, It changes only bars, and the chart still looks blur as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df_train= pd.read_csv('/home/udas/scratch/imageclefdata/Training-Concepts.csv',sep=';',names=["filename", "class"])  
import plotly.offline as py
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os
import gc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

pal = sns.color_palette()
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.tools as tls

labels = df_train['class'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for l in labels:
    for l2 in l:
        counts[l2] += 1

data=[go.Bar(x=list(counts.keys()), y=list(counts.values()))]
layout=dict(height=1200, width=800, title='Distribution of training labels')
fig=dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(data, filename='train-label-dist')
```

how can I change the colors, and make this chart more transparent?

Comment: change the colour

Comment: Can you please add an image of how it looks like and how you want it to look different? I don't understand what you problem is.

Comment: Sorry, it got deleted, while editing. Could you please look now.